# Java & OS X Maverick: Run a java application through an ssh connection fails

Tags: java, macos, ssh, x11

I'm trying to run a java program through an ssh connection, but I receives an error concerning the X11 Display.

Here all the steps & errors:

- My local

  ```
  > ssh user@ip_mac

  Connection succeed
  ```
- Then in my MAC OS (Maverick)

  ```
  > java -jar zzzzz.jar

  "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it"
  ```

So, I check it and the variable DISPLAY seems to be set:

```
    > echo $DISPLAY

    /tmp/launch-BVoaQK/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

If I open a terminal locally and do the same procedure, the java program runs well.

Any clue?

I tried also to run other applications (like Safari, Calculator, etc) and in these cases they run perfectly... It seems that it is just a java issue....

I used also the option "-Djava.awt.headless=true" but the problem is still there.

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution here?